# combining awk scripts for apache logs

Tags: apache, bash, awk

i'm not very good at scripting..

I have two scripts, the first one is to extract the last five minutes of my access_log , and the second one is to calculate the standard deviation of the apache response time so i can create a nagios alarm.

So , basically what i need is to calculate the standard deviation of the last five minutes of the access_log of the apache.

Could anyone give me a hand on this??

Script one

```
x=$((5*60))
last=$(tail -n1 access_log|awk -F'[][]' '{ gsub(/\//," ",$2); sub(/:/," ",$2); "date +%s -d \""$2"\""|getline d; print d;}' )

awk -F'[][]' -v last=$last -v x=$x '{ gsub(/\//," ",$2); sub(/:/," ",$2); "date +%s -d \""$2"\""|getline d; if (last-d<=x)print $0 }'
```

Script two

```
awk '{x[NR]=$11; s+=$11} END{a=s/NR; for (i in x){ss += (x[i]-a)^2} sd = sqrt(ss/NR); print "SD = "sd}' access_log
```

Gee, i've figured it out, the problem is that the second script actually parse the wrong line, so i'm attaching the correct script

```
# this variable you could customize, important is convert to seconds. 
# e.g 5days=$((5*24*3600))
x=$((5*60))   #here we take 5 mins as example

# this line get the timestamp in seconds of last line of your logfile
last=$(tail -n1 access_log2|awk -F'[][]' '{ gsub(/\//," ",$2); sub(/:/," ",$2);         "date    +%s -d \""$2"\""|getline d; print d;}' )


awk -F'[][]' -v last=$last -v x=$x '{ gsub(/\//," ",$2); sub(/:/," ",$2); "date +%s -d   \""$2"\""|getline d; if (last-d<=x)print $0 }' access_log2 | 
awk '{x[NR]=$14; s+=$14}   END{a=s/NR; for (i in x){ss += (x[i]-a)^2} sd = sqrt(ss/NR); print "SD = "sd}'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you give some sample input or the logs, as well as a bit explanation about where you are stuck?

Comment: Note that in the second script you're storing every response time into an array, so you can get a potentially huge array. You could avoid that by storing the running sum of the squares of the time, and doing some simple math with the square of the average.

Comment: By the way, I think that your second script work for me (averaging file size, cause my logs don't print response time)

Comment: @fedorqui , i've added the input example. Basically, as i told , iḿ not very good at this, so. I have this apache file, and when i pipe the output of the first script, the second one wont procces this output. for example, the last column of the apache log has nombers, i need to calculate the standard deviation of the last column of the last five minutes of the apache log

Comment: What is actually the problem with the above scripts? Do they produce unexpected results?

Comment: @RaulAndres , yes Raul, the problem is that i don't know how to put them together

Comment: @HåkonHægland i need to combine them both, need help on that couse just pipe out the first script on the second wont work

Comment: Pipe the output of the first into the second. It will work. Just remove the final  `access_log` from second script so awk gets input from stdin

Comment: As a side note, I am thinking that it would also be handy to change your apache log configuration, so that you do not have to parse the date so hard.

Comment: @RaulAndres i've tried that , i've added access_log at the end of the first script followed by a pipe and the second script, but the final output is "sd=0" that should'nt be the value

Comment: @fedorqui yeah, i know, but there are a lot of apache in here and they wont accept to modify them all

Comment: Mmm, what are you trying exactly? `cat yourinput|awk '{x[NR]=$11; s+=$11; s2+=$11*$11} END{welford=1/(NR*(NR-1))*(NR*s2-s*s);a=s/NR; for (i in x){ss += (x[i]-a)^2} sd = sqrt(ss/(NR-1)); sd2=
sqrt(welford);print "SD = "sd" "s" "a" "s2" "welford" "sd2}'` works fine (I've added Welford running method to compare)

Comment: @RaulAndres yes, the script works fine, but if i put them together like this: `awk -F'[][]' -v last=$last -v x=$x '{ gsub(/\//," ",$2); sub(/:/," ",$2); "date +%s -d \""$2"\""|getline d; if (last-d<=x)print $0 }' access_log | awk '{x[NR]=$11; s+=$11} END{a=s/NR; for (i in x){ss += (x[i]-a)^2} sd = sqrt(ss/NR); print "SD = "sd}'`  it does'nt work . the output is 0

Comment: @RaulAndres thanks buddy.. i've figured out that in the second script i was parsing the wrong column... my bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid to get EPOC time, here are my suggestions to simplify your question.

First, get time of 5 minutes before with below format:

```
MIN=$(date -d "-5 minutes" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```

For example, the time output will be something like : `20140114023124`

you can set 5 days before, or other time, whatever you like.

Then reformat the time part of access_log `[14/Jan/2014:02:36:50 +0100]` in awk or others, you should get `20140114023650` and compare with $MIN, if more than $MIN, print them out.

So the script will be (export the logs which were generated in 5 minutes).

```
MIN=$(date -d "-5 minutes" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
awk -F'[][]' -v m=$MIN '{ gsub(/\//," ",$2); sub(/:/," ",$2); "date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d \""$2"\""|getline d; if (d>=m) print }' access_log
```

You can attach the standard deviation calculation into awk command, or just export to the exist code: `awk '{x[NR]=$14; s+=$14}   END{a=s/NR; for (i in x){ss += (x[i]-a)^2} sd = sqrt(ss/NR); print "SD = "sd}'`